# Filter an array in Python3 / Numpy and return indices

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, filtering

Is there any built-in function in Python3/Numpy which filters an array and returns indices of the elements which are left? Something similar to numpy.argsort for sorting. The filter I have is setting both min and max thresholds - all values below/above min/max have to be filtered out.

I've seen Python's function [filter](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#filter), but I don't see a way to extract indices using it.

**EDITED:** Lots of useful information in the answers, thank you!

As @SvenMarnach pointed out, mask is enough:

```
mask = (min_value < a) & (a < max_value)
```

Now I have to apply this mask to other arrays of the same shape as `a`, but not sure what is the best way to do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the indices of the elements in the one-dimensional array `a` that are greater than `min_value` and les than `max_value` with

```
indices = ((min_value < a) & (a < max_value)).nonzero()[0]
```

Usually you don't need those indices, though, but you can work more efficiently with the mask

```
mask = (min_value < a) & (a < max_value)
```

This mask is an Boolean array with the same shape as `a`.

**Edit**: If you have an array `b` of the same shape as `a`, you can extract the elements of `b` corresponding to the `True` entries in `mask` with

```
b[mask]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for a quick reply. Indeed, mask is sufficient - but how do I apply this mask to some other array of the same shape as 'a'?

Comment: @Katya what would that mean? If you had a 5x5 array with a particular mask, could you define what that would mean to apply over a 4x3 or 6x6 array?

Comment: @Katya: What do you mean by "applying this mask"?  Extract the corresponding elements?  I added a sentence to my answer to that end.

Comment: @Hooked, By applying a mask I mean exactly "extract the elements of b corresponding to the True entries in mask", and proposed solution b[mask] works. I actually tried that but for some reason used a vector of 0s and 1s (the output of print(mask)), and not the original mask with True and False values - that gives wrong result. Thanks again, problem solved!

Answer (score 13):

The command `numpy.where` [will return the indices of an array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) after you've applied a mask over them. For example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,6,2])
np.where(A>2)
```

gives:

```
(array([2, 3]),)
```

A more complicated example:

```
A = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
np.where( (A>10) & (A<15) )
```

gives:

```
(array([1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 1]), array([2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

I'll agree with @SvenMarnach, usually you don't *need* the indices.

Comment: I had just created my own version of `where` when I saw this. Sigh.

Comment: @senderle it's probably slower too. Every time I think I know the full power of `numpy/scipy`, this site shows me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly related to your question, but `filter()` is part of a set of three functions, `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()`, which allow functional-style list processing in Python.

- `map(mapping_function, input_list)` takes in a function of one argument and a list, applies the function to each element of the list in turn, and returns an output list as the result. It's more or less equivalent to the list comprehension `[mapping_function(item) for item in input_list]`.
- `filter(filter_function, input_list)` returns a list of elements from `input_list` for which the `filter_function` returned `True`. The list comprehension equivalent is `[item for item in items if filter_function(item)]`.
- `reduce(combining_function, input_list)` repeatedly combines adjacent pairs of elements in the input list until only one value is left. For example the sum of a list of numbers could be expressed as `reduce(operator.add, numbers)`.

The functionality of `map()` and `filter()` is provided by list comprehensions in Python (which is why the `map` and `filter` functions aren't used very often.)

`reduce()` is one of those things which doesn't suggest itself as an intuitive answer to... anything. It's almost always clearer to write a loop, which explains why you don't see it often.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891688/577088)'s answer a lot, and in fact, [`numpy.where`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891802/577088) does exactly what you want, as Hooked reminded me. But mostly because I already wrote it out, here's another approach, just to illustrate a few tricks. `my_filter` can be any function returning a boolean array of the same shape as the input:

```
def my_filter(a):
    return (10 < a) & (a < 40)

a_mask = my_filter(a)
indices = [ind[a_mask] for ind in numpy.indices(a.shape)]
```

For example:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
>>> def my_filter(a):
...     return (min_value < a) & (a < max_value)
... 
>>> a_mask = my_filter(a)
>>> [ind[a_mask] for ind in numpy.indices(a.shape)]
[array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]), 
 array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3,
       4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need numpy, you can do it with a simple list comprehension and `enumerate`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2] 
[i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v > 2]
```

returns:

`[2, 3]`

Comment: It should be `[i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v > 2]` but yeah.. that approach works to. tnx suzana :)